# Attaching a Windows network drive on Ubuntu

Tags: networking, server, windows

I've been setting up a dev machine over the last week and I want to be able to network the drive on my host **Windows Server** machine, using hyper v, to my guest **Ubuntu Server** machine.

Server address is `\\SRV`

File share is `\\SRV\public_html` and is accessed on my guest Windows XP machine for shared verification.

Any links or suggestions would be awesome on how to do this from the terminal.

**Update**:

I used this to install samba http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/install-samba-server-on-ubuntu/
and, I created the cedentials file manually using `sudo touch credentials` as suggested by answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit /etc/fstab, add an entry like:

```
# Samba
//server/share  /media/samba  cifs  credentials=/etc/samba/credentials,uid=1000,gid=100  0  0
```

Where:
"Server" = Samba server (by IP or name if you have an entry for the server in your hosts file

"share" = name of the shared directory

In the credentials file put two lines

```
username=user 
password=password
```

Make the file owned by root and ro by root (sudo chown root.root /etc/samba/credentials && sudo chmod 400 /etc/samba/credentials)

Comment: I do not have a samba dir do I need to apt-get something?

Comment: I have only installed the core components.

Comment: You need to install samba to access to windows shares from Linux.

Answer (score 1):

About Hyper V I can't help you because never used it. The networking setup is Hyper-V specific, if possible you should set it up using NAT.

To access the shared drive from Ubuntu:
From the top panel.
Places -> Connect to Server -> Select Windows share and provide the required info.

Comment: Any idea how to do this from Ubuntu server terminal?